# Accessing ViewContext on multiple threads causing crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two `UIViewController`s in a Tab Bar

In one of the `TabBar` I am making an api call using `AFNetworking` and this api call is saving data in `CoreData`.

Here is my code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        for (int i = 0; i < cartList.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = [cartList objectAtIndex:i];
            NSFetchRequest *request = [Orders fetchRequest];
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderId = %@", [dict objectForKey:kiD]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *itemsList = context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            if (itemsList.count == 0)
            {
                Orders *order = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Orders" inManagedObjectContext:appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext];
                [order updateWithDictionary:dict];
                order.isNew = NO;
            }
            else
            {
                Orders *order = [itemsList objectAtIndex:0];
                [order updateWithDictionary:dict];
                order.isNew = NO;
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [appDel saveContext];
            [self refreshValues:NO];

        });
    });
```

In second `VIewController` I am doing something like that. If I switch the tab controllers very fast the app crashes at

```
 [appDel saveContext];
```

most probably because the last time `viewContext` was used by other `UIviewController` in Background thread.

What is the work around I can adopt to fix this problem

If this is correctly implemented

```
[appDel.persistentContainer performBackgroundTask:^(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nonnull context)
            {
                NSFetchRequest *request = [Categories fetchRequest];
                NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteReq = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request];

                NSError *deleteError = nil;
                [appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:deleteReq error:&deleteError];

                for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.count; i++)
                {
                    Categories *category = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext];
                    [category updateWithDictionary:[dataArr objectAtIndex:i]];
                }

                @try {

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    [context save:(&error)];
                } @catch (NSException *exception)
                {
                }

                [self getCategoryItems];
            }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core-data is not thread-safe, neither for reading for for writing.  If you violate this ever core-data can fail in unexpected ways.  So even if it appears to work you can find core-data suddenly crashing for no apparent reasons.  In other words, accessing core-data from the wrong thread is undefined.

There are a few possible solutions:

1) only use the main thread for reading and writing to core-data.  This is an OK solution for simple apps that don't do a lot of data import or export and have relatively small data sets.

2) Wrap `NSPersistentContainer`'s `performBackgroundTask` in an operation queue and only write to core-data through that method and never write to the `viewContext`.  When you use `performBackgroundTask` the method gives you a context.  You should use the context to fetch any objects that you need, modify them, save the context and then discard the context and the objects.

If you try to write using both `performBackgroundTask` and writing directly to the `viewContext` you can get write conflicts and lose data.

Comment: i read ur detailed explanation just now in another question, a couple of questions tho. When doing a fetch request for let's say 1000 entries, shouldnt i do it in background thread to avoid UI Freeze? also can u modify my code as an example how it should have been in first place

Comment: No. the UI will not freeze.  Fetches generally don't take that long.  1000 entries is a small dataset.

Comment: ok thanks , however after writing i need to call a function how would i do that , check my edits pls

Comment: I suggest that for you now you do everything on the main thread.

Comment: in performBackgroundTask do no access the `viewContext` or any viewContext object.  Use the `context` that is created for that block.  Also avoid `NSBatchDeleteRequest`  unless you have a large amount of data and a strong reason to use it.  It will delete stuff directly from the store and will not trigger fetchedResultsControllers.  Also I don't know what `getCategoryItems` does, but be aware that it is not running on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create a child `NSManagedObjectContext` object with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` your data processing in background queue.

Read [Concurrency guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) for more info.